# Duplicated output in Maxima

Tags: maxima

I implemented the bubble sort method in Maxima as:

```
burbuja(l) := block(
    for i : 1 step 1 thru length(l) do (
        for j : length(l) - 1 step -1 while j >= i do (
            if l[j] > l[j + 1] then (
                elemento : l[j],
                l[j] : l[j + 1],
                l[j + 1] : elemento
            )
        )
    ), print(l)
);
```

The problem is that the output is something like this:

```
(%i1) burbuja([3,2,1]);
[1, 2, 3]
(%o1) [1, 2, 3]
```

If I remove `print(l)` from the penultimate line, this is the output:

```
(%i1) burbuja([3,2,1]);
(%o1) done
```

The question is how can I print the result without duplicating it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `print(l)` just put `l` to return the value of `l` from the function. (Do not put `return(l)` as the effect of `return` is actually somewhat different from other languages.)

I also recommend copying the list before sorting it, so that you don't modify the original list. Try `l : copy(l)` before anything else.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement of Robert Dodier's answer, some more words for explaining what is happening. Maxima has a functional language with following features:

- last term in a block is also the value "returned" by this block;
- `print` has to be taken as a function rather than a mere statement.

These two ideas explain what happend in your case:

- the `print(l)` in your code **performs** something on your screen **but also is an expression** evaluating to l (try for instance something like `a:print(5)$` which will print the number 5 but also assign the value 5 to the variable a;
- since `print(l)` is also the last term in your block, your block will evaluate to l.

Thus your code prints l and also "return" it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Instead of `print(l)` I should use `append(l)`.